# In iOS, how can I stub Google Analytics SDK's [GAI sharedInstance] using Kiwi?

Tags: ios, objective-c, testing, google-analytics, kiwi

I'm using Kiwi for tests and when I try to stub the class method `[GAI sharedInstance]`, it doesn't work. Here is what I'm doing:

```
NSObject *gaiMock  = [KWMock nullMock];
[GAI stub:@selector(sharedInstance) andReturn:gaiMock];
```

When I break after these lines of code and compare them in the console, here is what I get:

```
(lldb) po [GAI sharedInstance]
<GAI: 0x10c42d940>

(lldb) po gaiMock
<KWMock: 0x112926600>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried swizzling `[GAI sharedInstance]`? Swizzling is never an ideal solution, but perhaps it could help in this case. Create a category on `GAI` at the top of your Kiwi test file, and override the `sharedInstance` method.

Comment: Good idea, I'll have to try that. But I still don't understand why what I'm doing is not working. Is it because I'm trying to stub a method of a static library?

Answer (score 0):

Try `[GAI stub:@selector(sharedInstance)...]`, as stub methods will work on class objects just like they do on instances.